# Add up the grades for each semester

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

want to calculate it every tahun_akademik_id

```
$jumlah = DB::table('penilaian')->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)->where('kategori_id','=', '2')->sum('nilai');
 $rata = DB::table('penilaian')->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)->where('kategori_id','=', '2')->avg('nilai');
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyCp9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `GROUP BY` clause which is provided by the `->groupBy()` function.

```
$jumlah = DB::table('penilaian')->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)->where('kategori_id','=', '2')->groupBy('tahun_akademik_id')->sum('nilai');
 $rata = DB::table('penilaian')->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)->where('kategori_id','=', '2')->groupBy('tahun_akademik_id')->avg('nilai');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy` for the same

As per Laravel Documenation:

> The `groupBy`  methods may be used to group the query results.

```
   $jumlah = DB::table('penilaian')
                ->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)
                ->where('kategori_id','=', '2')
                ->groupBy("tahun_akademik_id") //add this
                ->sum('nilai');

 $rata = DB::table('penilaian')
            ->where('penilaian.siswa_id', '=' ,$id)
            ->where('kategori_id','=', '2')
            ->groupBy("tahun_akademik_id") //add this
            ->avg('nilai');
```

[Laravel -> Query Builder -> Group By](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: @MarfinoHamzah don't forget to accept and upvote the answer. if it worked